# Sql Server Compact 4.0 provider missing

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I have been looking into using SQL Compact Editition 4.0 in a .NET 4.0 solution and I was doing fine until I decided to rename a bunch of projects and their namespaces. Since then, I lost the ability generate an EDMX model from an SDF file.

Usually, I'd add the EDMX as new item in my project, then "Generate from database" and from there I could create the SDF file using SQL Server Compact 4.0 provider. Of course this would generate an empty model but the provider was nonetheless available.

Now, all I get it:

[image: No CE!!]

I've tried uninstalling/installing SQL CE and its SP1, Visual Studio SQL CE 4.0 Tools SP1, no go.

Do I need to reformat my system drive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up uninstalling VS2010 and everything related to development on my workstation and installed this VS2010 addin: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/

Allows you to export an EDMX model into project type of any kind. :)

(Which you seem to be the author of, realized that after posting this, lol)

Answer (score 1):

The 4.0 Provider is only available in Web type Projects, not class library and desktop Projects. Workaround is to add a web type project and the move the .edmx afterwards (and the corresponing connection string in app.config/web.config)

Comment: Unless it was 'broken' when I first installed it, I can confirm I was designing my EDMX model with the 4.0 Provider from a .NET 4.0 Class Library project before all of this happened. Anyways, even in a Web Type project, the 3.5 AND 4.0 SQL CE providers are not shown.

Comment: Then they are not properly installed